# Java Sort Custom Objects Using Comparable, Collections.sort()

Tags: java, sorting, object, collections, comparable

I have two objects - RightTriangle and Rectangle. Both classes implement "Shape" interface which has 2 abstract methods for area and perimeter. In RightTriangle class I implement comparable and my compareTo returns area:perimeter ratio. I do the same thing in Rectangle class. In the demo I want to sort an array of RightTriangle objects and Rectangle Object using Collections.sort().

Shape Interface Code:

```
public interface Shape
{
    public double getArea();
    public double getPerimeter();
}
```

RightTriangle Code:

```
public class RightTriangle implements Shape, Comparable<Shape>
{
    private int leg1, leg2;
    public RightTriangle(int lg1, int lg2)
    {
        leg1 = lg1;
        leg2 = lg2;
    }


    public double getArea()
    {
        return (.5*leg1*leg2);
    }

    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return (leg1+leg2 + getHypotenuse());
    }   


    private double getHypotenuse()
    {
        return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(leg1,2)+Math.pow(leg2,2)));
    }

    public int compareTo(Shape obj)
    {
        return (int)(getArea()/getPerimeter());
    }

}
```

Rectangle Code:

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape, Comparable<Shape>
{
    private int length, width;

    public Rectangle(int l, int w)
    {
        length = l;
        width = w;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
        return (width*length);
    }

    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        return (2*width + 2*length);
    }

    public int compareTo(Shape obj)
    {
        return (int)(getArea()/getPerimeter());
    }

}
```

Demo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Demo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        RightTriangle right = new RightTriangle(12,14);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(7,10);
        ArrayList<Shape> al = new ArrayList<Shape>();
        al.add(right);
        al.add(rect);
        Collections.sort(al);
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println (al.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

I am getting an error - "error: no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList). How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `Shape` interface does not extend `Comparable`.

Comment: @tsolakp Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1. You need to extend Comparable interface to Shape interface and not traingle and rectangle class as below**

```
public interface Shape extends Comparable<Shape>
{
 public double getArea();
 public double getPerimeter();
 public int compareTo(Shape obj);
}
```

**2. RightTriangle and Rectangle class will only implement Shape interface as**

```
public class RightTriangle implements Shape
public class Rectangle implements Shape
```

**3. Implement toString method in both RightTriangle and Rectangle class by right click on code ..select source-> generate toString()

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RightTriangle [leg1=" + leg1 + ", leg2=" + leg2 + "]";
}

@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Rectangle [length=" + length + ", width=" + width + "]";
    }
```

** See the result i got after correcting your code
[image: See the result i got after correcting your code]